# Azure OAuth authentication packet for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

As part of a project we are implementing Azure OAuth authentication for a SQL Server instance hosted in the Azure cloud. We are using the MS-TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol to create the federated authentication packet which contain the access token data and the other parts needed in the packet.

We are now stuck at a point where no matter what we do, we are not able to get a successful response. As of now we are getting the below error from the server

> (47089) Reason: Login failed because Azure Dns Caching feature extension is malformed

Even though we are not populating anything related to DNS Caching in the packet knowingly. A major part of the problem is that we don't understand the error much by itself. We have looked over the internet and haven't really found much help yet. Do we have any resource we can refer to be able to understand this better? I mean the packet itself is huge and it is proving to be really difficult to debug this without any kind of documentation from Azure side.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems related, 1) [with own TDS protocol need help connecting azure SQL Server using generated AD access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/670782/with-own-tds-protocol-need-help-connecting-azure-s.html); 2) [Connecting azure SQL Server using generated Active directory access token #1724](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1724). Is your driver open source so that we can download the feature branch and try to inspect/debug it with Wireshark and similar tools?